# How do I implement ReCaptcha in a Single Page Application (SPA)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, recaptcha

I have a Single Page Application (SPA) I would like to add ReCaptcha to. 
This application is hosted using IIS as flat Html, Css & Javascript, this SPA in turn talks to a separate REST server (using CORS) for all dynamic content.

The REST server is written using ASP.net WebAPI. The problem is; all examples I have seen of ReCaptcha all use ASP.net MVC (or other languages) to inject html into the webpage, I cannot modify the webpage using ASP.net in this manor. Hopefully someone else has had the same problem.

I am really looking for some 2 parts, first the HTML that belongs on the client, and secondly the Controller that would be on the REST Server to verify with google. Even if this is in another language that I can convert, this will be useful!

Comment: Ofcourse after hours of searching, 10 mins after I submit I find something that may work. Checking out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/116250/Custom-reCaptcha-Validation. Will post if this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like what I wanted was simply to use reCaptcha without plugins (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)

Answer (score 0):

I have used ngx-captcha with my angular project.
Here's how I kept my submit button disabled until recaptcha checkbox is checked.

```html
   //code
 <ngx-recaptcha2 (success)="handleSuccess($event)"   #captchaElem [siteKey]="siteKey" formControlName="recaptcha">
                </ngx-recaptcha2>
```

once captcha is filled , it emits a success event , so use it in a method to make a variable true/false based on which you can enable/disable submit button

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! The answer you have provided above does not really address the question originally asked. If you would like to contribute information to a related question such as "How do I disable my submit button until recaptcha is pressed in angular", feel free to ask the question separately and add your own answer.

Comment: 0.2$: This comment may not even have been directly useful to me (I use a home-grown SPA architecture). However, the age of the question, the lack of a lot of answers and the fact that this answer referred to "keep my button disabled until" gave me the answer to MY question: "What does one, fundamentally, need to do to leverage the protection of captcha in a SPA?". Answer I needed: Simply disable until ready. So, thank you @Shweta Kumari